# How to use magnet links in LibTorrent lib

Tags: c++, c, magnet-uri

How to use magnet links in [LibTorrent C/C++ lib](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/manual.html#magnet-links)?
I need an simple example of working with it - Something like I give him a link he gives me a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I haven't used it personally, but you could check http://www.qbittorrent.org/, it uses libtorrent internally and it is under the GPL-2 license.